# How to calculate gcc compilation time?

Tags: c, gcc

I want to know GCC compile time. Does GCC have any command or option for calculate compile time?

I have a file named hello.c and will compile it. I want to know the time spent to compile it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `time` utility:

```
$ time gcc -c hello.c

real    0m0.224s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Here's a [link to the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time).

Comment: does the difference in time indicate wait state of process?

real = user + sys + time (process waiting for CPU).

trying to understand if there is  another factor to it ?

Comment: sys time is just how much time is spent in system calls. You want to use "real" time if you want to know how long the whole process took.

Answer (score 82):

To get a more comprehensive breakdown of compilation-time than what time can provide you can use `-ftime-report`:

```
g++ -s -O3 -ftime-report hello.c -o hello.exe

Execution times (seconds)
 callgraph construction:   0.01 ( 1%) usr     224 kB ( 1%) ggc
 callgraph optimization:   0.01 ( 1%) usr     147 kB ( 0%) ggc
 cfg cleanup           :   0.01 ( 1%) usr       8 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live regs          :   0.02 ( 2%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live&initialized regs:   0.01 ( 1%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 alias analysis        :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      67 kB ( 0%) ggc
 preprocessing         :   0.08 (10%) usr    2869 kB ( 8%) ggc
 parser                :   0.31 (40%) usr   24239 kB (66%) ggc
 name lookup           :   0.06 ( 7%) usr    3086 kB ( 8%) ggc
 inline heuristics     :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      16 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integration           :   0.01 ( 1%) usr    1499 kB ( 4%) ggc
 tree gimplify         :   0.01 ( 1%) usr     422 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree CFG cleanup      :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      12 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree VRP              :   0.01 ( 1%) usr     146 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree PTA              :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      66 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA rewrite      :   0.01 ( 1%) usr     159 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA incremental  :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      35 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree operand scan     :   0.01 ( 1%) usr     628 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree PRE              :   0.02 ( 3%) usr     101 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree FRE              :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      25 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dominance computation :   0.01 ( 1%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 expand                :   0.03 ( 4%) usr     528 kB ( 1%) ggc
 CSE                   :   0.01 ( 1%) usr       8 kB ( 0%) ggc
 CSE 2                 :   0.01 ( 1%) usr       6 kB ( 0%) ggc
 branch prediction     :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      67 kB ( 0%) ggc
 combiner              :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      48 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integrated RA         :   0.02 ( 2%) usr      53 kB ( 0%) ggc
 reload                :   0.01 ( 2%) usr     114 kB ( 0%) ggc
 reload CSE regs       :   0.01 ( 1%) usr      95 kB ( 0%) ggc
 final                 :   0.01 ( 1%) usr       3 kB ( 0%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :   0.79             36953 kB
```

This will work on any platform since you're using a switch supported by the compiler itself rather than relying on another timing program.

Comment: NOTE: if you are adding this flag on your CMake file (ie: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ftime-report")`), you might also want to add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to display the time reports.